# Kotlin Reflection not working on custom classes

Tags: kotlin, reflection

I have this wonderful method here:

```
fun Any.get(name : String) : Any{
    println(name)
    println(this::class.members.first{it.name == name} as KProperty1<Any,*>)
      return  (this::class.members.first { it.name == name } as KProperty1<Any, *>).get(this)!!
}
```

which I use with the class B:

```
open class Model(@Sql("id",true,true) var id : Int = 0)
open class A(val a : String, val b : User, @NoSql id : Int = 0) : Model(id)
class B(val c : Int, @NoSql a : String, @NoSql b : User, @NoSql id : Int = 0) : A(a,b,id)
```

When I try to retrieve the id, everything works as expected.
But when I try to retrieve the User, it throws:

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessException: class kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.calls.CallerImpl$Method cannot access a member of class com.gelbelachente.duckshit.db.models.ExtensionTest$A with modifiers "public final"
kotlin.reflect.full.IllegalCallableAccessException: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: class kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.calls.CallerImpl$Method cannot access a member of class com.gelbelachente.duckshit.db.models.ExtensionTest$A with modifiers "public final"
```

Additionally the console output:

```
id
var com.gelbelachente.duckshit.db.models.ExtensionTest.B.id: kotlin.Int
b
val com.gelbelachente.duckshit.db.models.ExtensionTest.B.b: server.db.models.User
```